# Python function handle ala Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

In MATLAB it is possible to create [`function handles`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html) with something like

```
myfun=@(arglist)body
```

This way you can create functions on the go without having to create M-files.

Is there an equivalent way in Python to declare functions and variables in one line and to call them later?

Comment: Are you looking for `lambda`?  What's wrong with `def`?

Comment: Just to correct the nomenclature: A function handle and an anonymous function are two different things. A handle is a reference to a function. An anonymous function is a lambda, a function created on the spot that doesn't have a name (in MATLAB they must have a single statement). The only way to refer to an anonymous function is through a handle, so these sometimes get confused.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python's lambda functions are somewhat similar:

```
In [1]: fn = lambda x: x**2 + 3*x - 4

In [2]: fn(3)
Out[2]: 14
```

However, you can achieve similar effects by simply defining `fn()` as a function:

```
In [1]: def fn(x):
   ...:   return x**2 + 3*x - 4
   ...: 

In [2]: fn(4)
Out[2]: 24
```

"Normal" (as opposed to lambda) functions are more flexible in that they allow conditional statements, loops etc.

There's no requirement to place functions inside dedicated files or anything else of that nature.

Lastly, functions in Python are first-class objects. This means, among other things, that you can pass them as arguments into other functions. This applies to both types of functions shown above.

Comment: Function handles can also be passed as arguments in Matlab.

Comment: @MatlabSorter: In python a function (or a lambda) can be passed as an argument to another function.  You don't need a "handle", you just pass the function itself.

Answer (score 15):

This is not quite the full answer.  In matlab, one can make a file called funct.m:

```
function funct(a,b)
   disp(a*b)
end
```

At the command line:

```
>> funct(2,3)
     6
```

Then, one can create a function handle such as:

```
>> myfunct = @(b)funct(10,b))
```

Then one can do:

```
   >> myfunct(3)
       30
```

A full answer would tell how to do this in python.

Here is how to do it:

```
def funct(a,b):
    print(a*b)
```

Then:

```
myfunct = lambda b: funct(10,b)
```

Finally:

```
>>> myfunct(3)
30
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is something that goes all the way back to 2.5 called [*function partials*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) that are pretty much the exact analogy to function handles.

```
from functools import partial
def myfun(*args, first="first default", second="second default", third="third default"):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
    print("first: " + str(first))
    print("second: " + str(second))
    print("third: " + str(third))

mypart = partial(myfun, 1, 2, 3, first="partial first")

mypart(4, 5, second="new second")
1
2
3
4
5
first: partial first
second: new second
third: third default
```